# RSA Chat Messenger(Number Format Exception in Java)

Tags: java

Im doing RSA chat messenger(single server,multiple clients).I have included send,decrypt,exit button.When client sends message from one client to other client.The client that recieves the message gets it in encrypted form and it clicks decrypt button to get original message.But when Im clicking decrypt button Im  getting AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException and getting wierd characters in decryption section.

Here is my code:

```
private String bytesToString(byte[] encrypted) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return null;
    String test = "";
    for (byte b : encrypted) {
        test += Byte.toString(b);
    }
    return test;
}

public static void main(String ... args) {

    // take username from user
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your name :", "Username",
         JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    String servername = "localhost";  
    try {
        new ChatClient( name ,servername);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        out.println( "Error --> " + ex.getMessage());
    }

} // end of main

// inner class for Messages Thread
class  MessagesThread extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        String line;
        try {
            while(true) {
                line = br.readLine();
                taMessages.append(line + "\n");
            } // end of while
        } catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
}
public class RSA {

    private BigInteger p;
    private BigInteger q;
    private BigInteger N;
    private BigInteger phi;
    private BigInteger e;
    private BigInteger d;
    private int bitlength = 1024;
    private int blocksize = 256; //blocksize in byte

    private Random r;
     public RSA() {
        r = new Random();
        p = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
        q = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength, r);
        N = p.multiply(q);

        phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
        e = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitlength/2, r);

        while (phi.gcd(e).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && e.compareTo(phi) < 0 ) {
            e.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
 d = e.modInverse(phi); 
    }

    public RSA(BigInteger e, BigInteger d, BigInteger N) {
        this.e = e;
        this.d = d;
        this.N = N;
    } 
    private String bytesToString(byte[] encrypted) {
        String test = "";
        for (byte b : encrypted) {
            test += Byte.toString(b);
        }
        return test;
    }

 //Encrypt message
     public byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) {     
        return (new BigInteger(message)).modPow(e, N).toByteArray();
    }

// Decrypt message
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) {
        return (new BigInteger(message)).modPow(d, N).toByteArray();
    } 
}

class Eavesdropper implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea myTextArea;
            public Eavesdropper(JTextArea ta) {
        myTextArea = ta;
    }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           RSA rsa = new RSA(); 
        //      String teststring = tfInput.getText();
      //    byte[] encrypted = rsa.encrypt(teststring.getBytes());  
        String text1 = taMessages.getText();
        String[] parts =text1.split("-");
           String part1=parts[1];
        part1 =part1.replaceAll("\n", "");
        byte[] b = part1.getBytes();
        byte[] decrypted = rsa.decrypt(b);       
        //RSAEncryption rsa=new RSAEncryption(1024);
    //  BigInteger plaintext = new BigInteger(part1.getBytes());
      //    BigInteger ciphertext = rsa.encrypt(plaintext);
        //String plaintext3 = rsa.decrypt(part1);
        //String text2 = new String(plaintext3.toByteArray());

              //    myTextArea.append(plaintext3);
        myTextArea.append("Decrypted String:" + new String(decrypted));
    }
}



} //  end of client
```

Comment: why are you implementing your own RSA?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

```
Throws: NumberFormatException - val is zero bytes long.
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5b%5d%29)